# Windows 10 wrong taskbar icon for explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, taskbar, icons

The issue:

On my Windows 10 build 1909 PC, when the explorer icon is open it shows the icon of the current navigation pane folder on my taskbar. I did few thing like rebuilding icons cache, but that did nothing to solve the issue.

Evidently I managed to mess up Explorer's settings somehow, most probably when I used Winaero Tweaker(?) because I did not touch Explorer's settings in any other way. I noticed this about 10 day ago and found no solution so far. But it is very annoying.

I found similar question (Windows Explorer icon showing wrong on taskbar asked Mar 26 at 16:23 by Akudaijin), but 1st: it was for Windows 7, 2nd: it seems that it was never answered.

Comment: A screenshot would really help here.

Comment: Updating Windows 10 could perhaps reset system icons to default

Comment: You question is really hard to understand. Are you able to explain in more detail what the problem is?

Comment: Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator. Run:  dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  .  Follow this with SFC /SCANNOW.   Restart the computer.  This should reset the Explorer icon. Does this work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I apologize if my question was unclear. Meanwhile I found a solution, but I'll try to rephrase my question anyway.

My Explorer was pinned on a taskbar. When I started the Explorer a second icon appeared and it was not the standard (yellow folder), but it was icon of the currently selected item in navigation panel, i.e. blue down arrow if Downloads folder was selected, drive icon id a drive was selected, etc.

I tried SFC /SCANNOW (like John suggested) but it did not help. As I solved the issue before I read John's suggestions I did not try the dism.exe part of it (but I'll try it on my other PC which also have some stubborn (but not so annoying) issues.

Solution was to restore Pin to taskbar context menu item, then remove all pinned programs from taskbar and in ten pin them again. There are many fixes for missing Pin to taskbar on the web, most of them did not work for me. At last I found fix that worked for me at https://troubleshooter.xyz/wiki/fix-pin-to-start-menu-option-is-missing-in-windows-10/. **Method 2** in that article is the one that worked for me.

Comment: I did the first thing in Method 2 and then I deleted one of the files in Method 3. Now for some reason I got the icons back, I don't know when, why and how. But now they are there again after doing a part of Method 2 and Method 3.